# How do you run "Quick Actions" in Photoshop scripts?

Tags: javascript, automation, photoshop, photoshop-script

I am trying to run a jsx script that will load an image, unlock the layer, use the "Remove Background" quick action, and save the image as a PNG. How do you trigger "Remove Background" quick action in scripts?

I have read through [Adobe's JavaScript documentation](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-javascript-ref-2020.pdf) and don't see anything about Quick Actions. I also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955699/running-a-photoshop-action-from-a-javascript-script) about triggering actions but did not see the "Remove Background" ATN file. I image is would look something like this:

```
app.doAction("RemoveBackground","RemoveBackground.ATN")
```

Is running the Remove Background quick action through scripts possible, and if so how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute an action with a script by using the following:

```
play_action("my action","my action Set");

function play_action(actionName, actionSetName)
{
    try
    {
        app.doAction(actionName,actionSetName);
    }
    catch(eek)
    {
        alert(eek + "\nAction not triggered");
    }
}
```

Where "my action",is the name of your action as a string - "remove background" and "my action Set" is the folder/ set in which it is in.

To remove a background simply search for the layer that has the flag `isBackgroundlayer`

```
// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var b = srcDoc.layers.length -1;

// search for background layer
if (srcDoc.layers[b].isBackgroundLayer == true)
{
  srcDoc.layers[b].remove();
}
else
{
  alert("No background layer found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I found a solution described on Instructables and hosted at GitHub, which does work. This is not my solution but I have successfully used it.

The action that you use to remove the background seems to be a compound action in which you select the subject using something labeled "autoCutout" and then invert the selection. I don't have enough knowledge to tell you anything more, other than that it works.

Warning: Photoshop did crash while I was using this.

Links here:

https://github.com/kavindupasan/batch-bg-remover-photoshop
https://www.instructables.com/Remove-Background-of-Multiple-Images-Using-Photosh/